Standalone display becomes browser in PWA after login via Google
Imagine I have a pwa with display: standalone configured in manifest. Everything works fine, browser navigation is not displayed before I log in via google, because of redirects after authorization, an application opens with display: browser. Does anyone know how to fix this so that there is always display: standalone?
I expect that setting display standalone should work correctly. Are there any other important settings in manifest that allow you to achieve the desired result?

You can use the messaging api to send feedback to the opener, and let the opener close the popup (example)
